# Fetch current lightning URL

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, forcenavigatetourl

I want to understand if there is any way to fetch the current lightning component url in salesforce and navigate to it

I am using

```
window.location.href = window.location.pathname;
```

in my lightning component for redirection, but it is taking me to classic instead of the lightning view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable"` to get the URL and its parameter.

And use pageReference for navigation. [Is Url Addressable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation)

```
var navService = component.find("navService");
var pageReference = component.get("v.pageReference");
event.preventDefault();
navService.navigate(pageReference);
```